# How to find element wise mean of two pandas series in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I have faced this question in one of the technical rounds of a company.
The question was that there are two series given below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
series_A = pd.Series([10,15,12,20])
series_B = pd.Series([12,19,65,13])
```

we have to find the element-wise mean of these two series and store the results in new series series_C

My approach

```
series_C = pd.Series(np.mean(series_A,series_B))
```

but it is giving error
***"TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"***

Answer (score 4):

IIUC:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
series_A = pd.Series([10,15,12,20])
series_B = pd.Series([12,19,65,13])

series_C = (series_A+series_B)/2
```

Using numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
series_A = pd.Series([10,15,12,20])
series_B = pd.Series([12,19,65,13])

series_C = pd.concat([series_A, series_B], axis=1).agg(np.mean, 1)
0    11.0
1    17.0
2    38.5
3    16.5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

numpy mean takes as first argument an ndarray and as second argument the axis along which to preform the mean.

what you need to do is to store the series in some kind of array like so

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
series_A = pd.Series([10,15,12,20])
series_B = pd.Series([12,19,65,13])
series_C = pd.Series(np.mean(np.stack((series_A, series_B)), axis=0))
```

which give us:

```
series_C
0    11.0
1    17.0
2    38.5
3    16.5
dtype: float64
```